# is it possible to set column width and Background color for table headers

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-addins, word-table

I am trying to create a table in word document using Office Js.

I need to set the width for the two columns at 20% resp. 80%.

The table header should be formatted with a background color.

[image]

I tried using this code

```
var Table = body.insertTable(2, array.length, Word.InsertLocation.start, [array]); 
Table.styleBuiltIn = Word.Style.GridTable1Light_Accent1
```

I can't find the correct properties.

The entire function

```
function createTable() {    
  Word.run(function (context) {
    var body = context.document.body;
    var Table = body.insertTable(2, array.length, Word.InsertLocation.start, [array]);    
    return context.sync();
  })
  .catch(errorHandler);
}
```

Comment: The Table object has a `shadingColor` property, but I'm not sure if that's what you want. The TableCell object has a `columnWidth` property. You might try setting that for a cell in the column. You should also look at the Table object's `style` and `builtinStyle` properties.

Comment: Hi @RickKirkham i added the screenshot i m trying achieve that.I tried Style and Builtinstyle with different values nothing seems to be working. Please find the sample code which i tried             var Table = body.insertTable(2, array.length, Word.InsertLocation.start, [array]);

            Table.styleBuiltIn = Word.Style.GridTable1Light_Accent1;

Comment: Please describe how the code you have for formatting the table is not working. When I test it here (replacing the array information since I don't have that with static values) a formatted table is inserted. The colors are not the same as in the picture, but that's because the style name you use is not the same as the picture.

Comment: As for the column widths, please ask this as a new question. The Word JS APIs apparently do not support this (yet), which means a OOXML approach...